# Draw plot and display results Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

I'm working on bisection method which I wrote by myself. The following code works fine - it displays correct results(Tested on x^2-25) and it gave correct results. But that's not all what I wanted to realize.I need draw a plot displaying all correct results on it.

As I told - I took expression

> x^2-25

, and results are

> 5 and -5

Now, I need to draw parabola and display results.

My Code

```
function [] = bisectionWindow()
clc;
f = @(x) x^2-25; % specified function
a=5;
b=6;
e=0.0001;

syms x;
% Main loop
while abs(b-a)>e
    c=(b+a)/2;
    if sign(f(c)) == sign(f(a))
        a=c;
    else
        b=c;
    end
end
 disp(['Answer x='])
 solve(f(x))
 %note: ans displays because of 'sign' operator presence
```

My Attempt to draw plot

```
function [] = checkWin(a,b,x)
%draws plot
 Limits = [a b];
 len = b-a;
 for i=1:len
     x = X(i);
     y=x^2-25;
     %y=0.5*x^3-2*x^2+1;
     figure(1),clf,hold on
     fplot('x^2-25',Limits),grid
         plot(x,y,'o')
 end
end
```

UPD: To clear some things up

I understand how to draw a plot. My objective is:

1. Show the plot
2. Show results as o's on it

The problem is - this should be unique code (as for example i took parabola,  but let's take another function which has only one result) and it should execute things metioned above. So basically this is why i'm working on.

There's 2 options:

1. Modify existing code - which i dunno how
2. Rewrite - no ideas how.

I'm stuck for a long time I guess.

Thanks for Advices.

Comment: So read the documentation for [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)...

Comment: i did it but still don't get it how to draw a plot and display the results of x variable

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Question Updated.  It shows -9.0313 as a correct answer, which is not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you need the loop in your code. The following script works fine and gives the same result as yours:

```
f = @(x) x^2-25; % specified function
disp(['Answer x='])
disp(solve(f(x)))
```

You can plot your function by typing `ezplot(f)`:
[image]

Typing `ezplot(f,[-5,5])` would plot function with x between -5 and 5
If you want to use `plot` function, you need to rewrite your function as:

```
f = @(x) x.^2-25
```

This is because `^2` operation is regarded as multiplication of matrix by itself that is inapplicable to vectors, whereas `.^2` is squaring of each matrix element.
Then, you need to create two vectors with x and y data and use plot function:

```
x = -10:0.1:10;
y = f(x);
plot(x,y), grid on
```

where `grid on` provides your plot with gridlines. There are many other plot options that you can use to customize your graph. You can find them [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

[image]

UPD. Modified code with comments:

```
f = @(x) x.^2-25; %//specified function
disp(['Answer x='])
q = solve(f); %//-5 and 5 would be in one vector
disp(q) %//display -5 and 5
h = ezplot(f,[-10,10]); %//plot f(x) from -10 to 10
grid on; %//add grid to plot
set(h,'LineWidth',3); %//set line width to 3px
hold on;%//prevent the current graph from being replaced
plot(q,f(q),'ro','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',3)
%//plot two O-s at -5 and 5. Also, make O-s 10px in width and 3px thick
hold off;
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a great post! The next question might be stupid (just because i'm unable to test it atm). How could i exactly show the results on this? Following code could resolve this?
`x = -10:0.1:10;
y = f(x);
plot(x,y,'o'), grid on
`

That's really need to know. I must show all possible results as points (in this case 5 and -5) or atleast only 5.

Comment: @h3dge I would rather add `hold on; plot([-5,5],f([-5,5]),'ro')` to the above code. This would add two red O-s at points (-5,f(-5)) and (5,f(5))